# Sortable jQuery mobile list; with local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, local-storage, jquery-mobile-listview

I have a jQuery mobile list which has a swipe to delete function and stores preferences locally. I am trying to implement a functionality to re-order the list items and store this within the same array, please help!
Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f18nfz/nUSUB/2/

So the function could be something like (http://jsfiddle.net/maziar/P2XDc/):

```
function moveUp(item) {
    var prev = item.prev();
    if (prev.length == 0)
        return;
    prev.css('z-index', 999).css('position','relative').animate({ top: item.height() }, 250);
    item.css('z-index', 1000).css('position', 'relative').animate({ top: '-' + prev.height() }, 300, function () {
        prev.css('z-index', '').css('top', '').css('position', '');
        item.css('z-index', '').css('top', '').css('position', '');
        item.insertBefore(prev);
    });
}
function moveDown(item) {
    var next = item.next();
    if (next.length == 0)
        return;
    next.css('z-index', 999).css('position', 'relative').animate({ top: '-' + item.height() }, 250);
    item.css('z-index', 1000).css('position', 'relative').animate({ top: next.height() }, 300, function () {
        next.css('z-index', '').css('top', '').css('position', '');
        item.css('z-index', '').css('top', '').css('position', '');
        item.insertAfter(next);
    });
}

$(".FieldContainer").sortable({ items: ".OrderingField", distance: 10 });
$('button').click(function() { 
    var btn = $(this);
    var val = btn.val();
    if (val == 'up')
        moveUp(btn.parents('.OrderingField'));
    else
        moveDown(btn.parents('.OrderingField'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice example of a sortable drag&drop list with jQuery Mobile: http://jsfiddle.net/sidonaldson/pes2d/

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
            <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">Re-order</li>
            <li data-theme="c">1</li>
            <li data-theme="c">2</li>
            <li data-theme="c">3</li>
            <li data-theme="c">4</li>
            <li data-theme="c">5</li>
            <li data-theme="c">6</li>
            <li data-theme="c">7</li>
        </ul>
        <a data-role="button">Submit</a>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('li').removeClass('ui-corner-bottom');
    $('ul')
        .addClass('ui-corner-top')
        .removeClass('ui-corner-all')
        .sortable({
            'containment': 'parent',
            'opacity': 0.6,
            update: function(event, ui) {
                alert("dropped");
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: As my list is quite long and you'd need to scroll through it I wanted buttons or alternatively if I could have only an icon or button on every list item draggable that could work...